# RでNAを含む連続変数がカテゴリー変数と判断されます

Tags: r

Rで-100から∔100までの連続変数（ただし計算上は±5毎に区切られます）の平均、SD値を、条件A/B群でそれぞれ比較し、TableOneで解析をしています。

この連続変数（BI_dif）の中にＮＡが多数あるからでしょうが、TableOneを作成すると、5毎のカテゴリー変数別に割合が表示され、平均・SD値が表示できません。

```
pt_01_excel %>% replace_na((list(BI_dif="NA"))
pt_01_excel %>% mutate(BI_dif=na_if(BI_dif,NA))
as.numeric(match_data_excel$BI_dif)
match_data_excel$BI_dif[is.na(match_data_excel$BI_dif)]<-"N"
```

上記のように色々NAを変換させようとしましたが、Characterのままになり、doubleに変換できません。ご教示ください。

Answer (score 0):

`BI_dif` の要素を double 型に変換するのであれば下記になります。 なお，`as.numeric()` の代わりに `as.double()` も使えます。

```
match_data_excel$BI_dif <- as.numeric(match_data_excel$BI_dif)
```

御参考として簡単な実行例を下記に示します。

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2.1, NA, NA, 2.4, NA),
                 b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
typeof(df$a)
## [1] "double"
typeof(df$b)
## [1] "logical"

df$b <- as.numeric(df$b)
typeof(df$b)
## [1] "double"
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました。